# PHP Variable Functions and language constructs

Tags: php, function, variables

I'm trying to understand why [PHP documentation for variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) states that:

> Variable functions won't work with language constructs such as echo,
>   print, unset(), isset(), empty(), include, require and the like.
>   Utilize wrapper functions to make use of any of these constructs as
>   variable functions.

I tried some of these and they work just fine:

```
function animal() {

    return 'Monkey';

}

$animal = 'animal';

echo $animal();
```

returns `Monkey` - just as one would expect.

Same result with `print` construct - then I tried `unset()` and it also works absolutely fine:

```
function getIndex() {

    return 0;

}

$index = 'getIndex';

$array = array(

    'Monkey',
    'Gorilla'

);

unset($array[$index()]);

print_r($array);
```

this returns `Array ( [1] => Gorilla )`.

Is there something I'm missing here? Just to add - I'm using PHP 5.5.14.

Comment: what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Try `$function = 'echo'; $function('Hello World');`

Comment: I think I got it - Originally I thought that you won't be able to use these constructs with the variable function, but I believe they simply refer to the fact that you cannot declare variable with 'echo' ( $echoVariable = 'echo' ) for instance and call it as function: $echoVariable().

Comment: Thanks Mark - that's what I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually using any language constructs as a variable function:

But try

```
$function = 'echo'; 
$function('Hello World');
```

and it won't work, exactly as described in the docs

Use a wrapper function around echo as described in the manual, and then you can use that function as a variable function

```
function myecho($value) {
    echo $value;
}

$function = 'myecho'; 
$function('Hello World');
```

Comment: Thanks Mark - weird how sometimes your brain freezes :)

Answer (score 2):

They mean another usage:

```
<?php
$var = "some variable";
$a = "unset"; //also print, isset, echo, include

// you cannot do this:
$a($var);
```

Of course you can unset or print variable with string containing function name...

(Or am I missing something? :) )

Comment: That's precisely what I've figured a minute after I've posted this ticket :) Thanks Mike.